# php - How to use complex (like derived tables and subqueries) queries with Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I stuck on the laravel query builder. It's a nice to feature of laravel. I think it's not good for complex SQL queries.
I write a query to select mutual connections of 2 people from the database but I don't know how to code it using the laravel query builder

My SQL Query :

```
    SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        connections
    WHERE
        connections.user_id = '107' OR connections.connection = '107'
) AS UserAConnetions
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        connections
    WHERE
        connections.user_id = '106' OR connections.connection = '106'
) AS UserBConnetions
ON
    (
        UserBConnetions.user_id = UserAConnetions.user_id OR UserAConnetions.connection = UserBConnetions.connection OR UserBConnetions.user_id = UserAConnetions.connection OR UserAConnetions.user_id = UserBConnetions.connection
    )
```

I'm building a social network so and I need to get users name and profile picture after getting mutual friends

Comment: can you share your db tables structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your models you should define relationships and then use it with your eloquent.

For example:

```
$users = User::with('connections') -> get();
```

like that.

[Laravel Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships)

Read it. it's very simple and gives you quite a flexibility.